# image size comparison in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have two images `A` and `B`.
I want to compare the size of the two images.

```
if A>B 
then 
    A=A; and B=B; 
else
    swap them
```

How can I do this in MATLAB? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numel`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) to find the number of pixels in an image. E.g. for a `16 x 16` image, `numel` will return `256`.

```
% If image A is smaller or equal as image B, swap the two images
if numel(A) <= numel(b)
    tmp = A;
    A = B;
    B = tmp;
    clear('tmp');
end
```

This only looks at the total number of pixels in each image. If you want to take the shape into account, you can use the [`size`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) function to get the width and height of the image:

```
[height,width] = size(image)
```

Then you'd have to think of some logic, whether to swap or not: what if a is wider, but less high, and so on.

Comment: thanks @hbaderts. i am working on template matching. so by default system asks for source image to load first then template image means source image  should be greater than template image. but i want to load both image in any order. so by checking size after loading i can decide which one is larger. so give me idea according to that.

Comment: thank  you very much. i did it. actually there is main module and sub module(function definition). so i gave your condition and swap the sub module arguments.